# Infragistics WebDataGrid RowAdding: Are there no CheckBox editor providers?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

In my `ig:WebDataGrid` there are two columns that hold boolean values coming from a database; the column is defined via

```
<ig:BoundCheckBoxField Key="Mandatory" DataFieldName="Mandatory" Header-Text="test" />
```

Every editing option (be it `RowEditing` or `CellEditing`) works fine with the automatically provided CheckBoxes that represent the values. But now I want to use the `RowAdding` feature. Unfortunately I can't find any EditorProvider that seems to fit for CheckBoxes, and just leaving the definition for the respective columns empty results in the cells not being clickable/editable in the adding row, although there are grayed out CheckBoxes shown and the column is not set to be `ReadOnly`.

Is there any way to get an editor provider fit for this? Since editing works automatically with the CheckBoxes I feel like there should be an easy way to get `RowAdding` to work analogously. Otherwise I'd have to go the 'painful' way via creating a DropDown Provider with 'true/false' as values... which would be way less elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a bug in the specific Infragistics version we were using. Updating to the latest Service Release of the 14.1 controls fixed this particular problem. Although there is indeed no CheckBox editor provider, those just work by default now.